# Eclipse Indigo Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

It started with the R error (which is not going how much ever I clean the project), then even through I selected the target SDK as 18, the format it showed on creation of the project was that of Kitkat (19) and then it said repository not found at a weird location.

Now when I try to check for updates, it stops after 16% and gives me the following error:

Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.

```
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/1.3/runtime.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/emf/updates/.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/emft/jet/update-site/site.xml.
HTTP Server 'Internal Error': http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/dsdp/org.eclipse.tm.tcf/releases/0.4.0/content.xml
HttpClient connection error response code 500.

No repository found at http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=papyrus#papyrus.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/e3.4/.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.1/update-site/.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ptp/updates/indigo/.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/eef/updates/0.7.1/.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/site.xml.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/stp/updates/.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/releases/.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20100519200754/repository.
No repository found at http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/?project=search#search.

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/1.3/tooling.
```

Can anyone help?

P.S. The R error is still prevalent. Its not going.

Comment: I will suggest you to use Eclipse Juno which is using as an industrial standard in the market. :)

Comment: Which Java version you are using? If it is 1.7 change it to 1.6. It fix problem

Comment: It's 1.6. You mean environment variable. Right?